# ASP.NET development without internet connection

Tags: asp.net

How do I configure Visual Studio 2010 such that I do not need an internet connection to develop a web app in ASP.NET?
For many weeks since I installed Visual Studio I was developing and testing several test web apps without a permanent connection.
Since I use a wireless connection at home it seems that the ability to run a web app in VS 2010 is lost. I prefer to work without a permanent connection because it distracts me too much.

Does anyone know how I can restore the situation?

Krook

Comment: What do you need an Internet connection for at the moment when developing?

Comment: I don't, the point is that Visual Studio refuses to open an aspx page when I am not connected ever since I have a wireless connection.

Comment: Where is it expecting the `.aspx` page to live? Locally? Remotely?

Comment: locally , everything worked just fine before a had a wireless connection. remotely is impossible by definition, I understand that.  On my own computer I have my own ASP.NET web application projects,  and I want to open my own aspx pages by rightclicking and choosing "View in browser" . That's all. It does work when I am connected though. I just want it to work also when I am not connected as well.

Comment: i think you are connected to a database that is online or u r using svn or something like that, can we see your connection string?

Comment: no no it is not about a connection string at all. I tested the problem with a new almost empty web project with only one aspx file and no SQL server connection. It is also not an SVN issue, these test projects are not in SVN.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to get Visual Studio to run and execute a web site locally.  You state several times that it doesn't work; however, you've never said what exactly doesn't and the error messages you get.  Basically, you need to tell us exactly what isn't working and/or why you think it's not working.

Comment: I know I don't need anything special. The point is that it all worked just fine without internet connection until I had a permanent wireless connection. When I consciously disconnect from my home wireless station and I want to open my default.aspx I get a window telling me to connect to the internet. When I click Cancel I get an error page on IE 9 telling me that I am not connected to the Internet.
That is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click home page in Solution Explorer, select "`File -> Browse with`" and pick the browser of your choice? If it's IE, then go to "File - Work Offline" in IE and toggle that setting.